# How can I use overloaded record fields with lenses?

Tags: haskell, typeclass, haskell-lens

It's possible to mix classes with lenses to simulate overloaded record fields, up to a point. See, for example, `makeFields` in [Control.Lens.TH](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.13.1/docs/Control-Lens-TH.html). I'm trying to figure out if there's a nice way to reuse the same name as a *lens* for some types and a *traversal* for others. Notably, given a sum of products, each product can have lenses, which will degrade to traversals of the sum. The simplest thing I could think of was this**:

#### First try

```
class Boo booey where
  type Con booey :: (* -> *) -> Constraint
  boo :: forall f . Con booey f => (Int -> f Int) -> booey -> f booey
```

This works fine for simple things, like

```
data Boop = Boop Int Char
instance Boo Boop where
  type Con Boop = Functor
  boo f (Boop i c) = (\i' -> Boop i' c) <$> f i
```

But it falls on its face as soon as you need anything more complicated, like

```
instance Boo boopy => Boo (Maybe boopy) where
```

which should be able to produce a `Traversal` regardless of the choice of underlying `Boo`.

#### Second try

The next thing I tried, which sort of works, is to constrain the `Con` family. This gets kind of gross. First, change the class:

```
class LTEApplicative c where
  lteApplicative :: Applicative a :- c a

class LTEApplicative (Con booey) => Boo booey where
  type Con booey :: (* -> *) -> Constraint
  boo :: forall f . Con booey f => (Int -> f Int) -> booey -> f booey
```

This makes `Boo` instances carry around *explicit evidence* that their `boo` produces a `Traversal' booey Int`. Some more stuff:

```
instance LTEApplicative Applicative where
  lteApplicative = Sub Dict

instance LTEApplicative Functor where
  lteApplicative = Sub Dict

-- flub :: Boo booey => Traversal booey booey Int Int
flub :: forall booey f . (Boo booey, Applicative f) => (Int -> f Int) -> booey -> f booey
flub = case lteApplicative of
         Sub (Dict :: Dict (Con booey f)) -> boo

instance Boo boopy => Boo (Maybe boopy) where
  type Con (Maybe boopy) = Applicative
  boo _ Nothing = pure Nothing
  boo f (Just x) = Just <$> hum f x
    where hum :: Traversal' boopy Int
          hum = flub
```

And the base `Boop` example works unchanged.

#### Why this still sucks

We now have `boo` producing a `Lens` or `Traversal` under appropriate circumstances, and we can always *use* it as a `Traversal`, but every time we want to do so, we have to first drag in the evidence that it really is one. This is, of course, *far* too inconvenient for the purpose of implementing overloaded record fields! Is there any nicer way?

** This code compiles with the following (may not be minimal):

```
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds, TypeFamilies,
     TypeOperators, FlexibleContexts,
     ScopedTypeVariables, RankNTypes,
     KindSignatures #-}

import Control.Lens
import Data.Constraint
```

Comment: Is it really so inconvenient? `flub` can be written once and for all - so just call it `boo`, and rename `boo` to `booWithCon`. The user never has to know about `booWithCon` or any underlying machinery. And for an implementer, it takes one extra line for an instance as compared to approach 1 - what precisely would you consider an inconvenience?

Comment: @user2407038, the ideal I'm aiming for is that the name `boo` will be usable as either a `Lens` (where available) or only a `Traversal` (otherwise). `flub` is only ever a `Traversal`; it's never a `Lens`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following has worked for me before:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, FlexibleInstances #-}

import Control.Lens

data Boop = Boop Int Char deriving (Show)

class HasBoo f s where
  boo :: LensLike' f s Int

instance Functor f => HasBoo f Boop where
  boo f (Boop a b) = flip Boop b <$> f a

instance (Applicative f, HasBoo f s) => HasBoo f (Maybe s) where
  boo = traverse . boo
```

It can be also scaled to polymorphic fields, if we make sure to enforce all the relevant functional dependencies (just like [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.13.1/docs/Control-Lens-Tuple.html)). Leaving an overloaded field completely polymorphic is rarely useful or a good idea; I illustrate that case though because from there one can always monomorphize as necessary (or we can constrain polymorphic fields, for example a `name` field to `IsString`).

```
{-# LANGUAGE
  UndecidableInstances, MultiParamTypeClasses,
  FlexibleInstances, FunctionalDependencies, TemplateHaskell #-}

import Control.Lens

data Foo a b = Foo {_fooFieldA :: a, _fooFieldB :: b} deriving Show

makeLenses ''Foo

class HasFieldA f s t a b | s -> a, t -> b, s b -> t, t a -> s where
  fieldA :: LensLike f s t a b

instance Functor f => HasFieldA f (Foo a b) (Foo a' b) a a' where
  fieldA = fooFieldA

instance (Applicative f, HasFieldA f s t a b) => HasFieldA f (Maybe s) (Maybe t) a b where
  fieldA = traverse . fieldA
```

One can also go a bit wild and use a single class for all "has" functionality:

```
{-# LANGUAGE
  UndecidableInstances, MultiParamTypeClasses,
  RankNTypes, TypeFamilies, DataKinds,
  FlexibleInstances, FunctionalDependencies,
  TemplateHaskell #-}

import Control.Lens hiding (has)
import GHC.TypeLits
import Data.Proxy

class Has (sym :: Symbol) f s t a b | s sym -> a, sym t -> b, s b -> t, t a -> s where
  has' :: Proxy sym -> LensLike f s t a b

data Foo a = Foo {_fooFieldA :: a, _fooFieldB :: Int} deriving Show
makeLenses ''Foo

instance Functor f => Has "fieldA" f (Foo a) (Foo a') a a' where
  has' _ = fooFieldA
```

With GHC 8, one can add

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}
```

and avoid the proxies:

```
has :: forall (sym :: Symbol) f s t a b. Has sym f s t a b => LensLike f s t a b
has = has' (Proxy :: Proxy sym)

instance (Applicative f, Has "fieldA" f s t a b) => Has "fieldA" f (Maybe s) (Maybe t) a b where
  has' _ = traverse . has @"fieldA"
```

Examples:

```
> Just (Foo 0 1) ^? has @"fieldA"
Just 0
> Foo 0 1 & has @"fieldA" +~ 10
Foo {_fooFieldA = 10, _fooFieldB = 1}
```

Comment: Very nice. I'm still working through it, but it seems to provide a much nicer interface than what I came up with.